# Расширение области печати в Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Собственно вопрос в этом и заключается. Как расширить программно (C#) область печати (границы) в Excel файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойство [PageSetup.PrintArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup.printarea.aspx):

```
IPageSetup pageSetup = worksheet.PageSetup;
pageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:H42";
```

Comment: Да спасибо. В моём случае для настройки горизонтальной области печати использовал:  `ExcelWorkSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin  = 10;
            ExcelWorkSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 10; `